# Android: Wait for object to appear

Tags: java, android, object, null, exists

I cannot think of a proper way to wait for an object to appear. I am writing a camera app. After taking a picture, I am writing GPS Data into the exif tags. I have to wait for the location object to appear, before writing. My quick and dirty fix is to start a new thread and use a while loop to "wait" for the object:

```
      private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
         private final String imagePath;
         private final String thumbPath;
         MyRunnable(final String anImagePath, String aThumbPath) {
           this.imagePath = anImagePath;
           this.thumbPath = aThumbPath;
         }

         public void run() {
             while (mCurrentLocation == null) {
                 //do nothing
             }
             try {
             writeExifTags(imagePath);
             writeExifTags(thumbPath);
             }
             catch (NullPointerException e) {
                 Log.i(TAG, "NullPointerException");
             }
         }
      }
```

This works but the empty while-loop looks very ugly. I think of some kind of handler for the object but cannot think of a way to use handlers to check for the existence of mCurrentLocation. Anyone with a flash of wit? :) (Yes the try/ catch block is obsolete now ^^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using an AsyncTask?

Comment: well, I could. But I don't sse any advantage over my current Method. Besided my "main" question is how to check periodically for an object to be null. An advantage may be a sleep/ wait in the while-loop...

Comment: I see. What about using the handlers like you said, and use method assignment as they only way to modify the mCurrentLocation. When you use the method to assign it to null fire the handle event.

Comment: I implemented AsyncTask for the problem. The code looks cleaner (although is does exactly the same). My motivation is a bit low to dig into handlers, as the problem is already solved. I added "Thread.sleep(1);" to the while loop. That seems acceptable for me. Thanks nonetheless for your help.:)